# no respond when join table with .net

Tags: .net, mysql, join

I have two queries that I want to join

```
SELECT b.nickname,count(a.doctor_id) 
FROM a_table a 
join b_table b 
on (a.doctor_id=b.id_user) 
GROUP BY a.doctor_id
```

and

```
SELECT   doctor_id, SUM(medicine) medicine, SUM(radiology) radiology,sum(lab) lab, sum(act) act
FROM     (
  SELECT   MAX(doctor_id) doctor_id,
           SUM(IF(pm='F', cost, NULL)) medicine,
           SUM(IF(pm='R', cost, NULL)) radiology,
           SUM(IF(pm='L', cost, NULL)) lab,
           SUM(IF(pm='P', cost, NULL)) act
  FROM     c_table
  GROUP BY Trans_No
) t
GROUP BY doctor_id
```

I already tried to join

```
SELECT   b.nickname, count(a.doctor_id), SUM(medicine) medicine, SUM(radiology) radiology,sum(lab) lab, sum(act) act
FROM     (
  SELECT   MAX(doctor_id) doctor_id,
           SUM(IF(pm='F', cost, NULL)) medicine,
           SUM(IF(pm='R', cost, NULL)) radiology,
           SUM(IF(pm='L', cost, NULL)) lab,
           SUM(IF(pm='P', cost, NULL)) act
  FROM     c_table
  GROUP BY Trans_No
) t
join a_table a on (a.doctor_id=t.doctor_id)
join b_table b on (a.doctor_id=b.id_user)
GROUP BY a.doctor_id
```

all of these table has a large amount of data (more than 2 million data), I already set my CommandTimeout = 600 but it still has no respond

did I join it wrong or it's just to many data? what am I supposed to do to get the result?

Comment: How long does the query take to run when you run it directly on the database instead of from code?  What does it return?

Comment: Have you looked at the estimated execution plan to see what might be happening?  Are the tables indexed appropriately?  Are the index statistics current?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer, but it is too long for a comment.

Your queries do not make sense.  I think you need to look again at the problem.  The first query:

```
SELECT b.nickname,count(a.doctor_id) 
FROM a_table a 
join b_table b 
on (a.doctor_id=b.id_user) 
GROUP BY a.doctor_id
```

is *always* going to return 1 for `count(a.doctor_id)`, except when doctor_id is NULL.  This is because you are grouping on that column.  Do you mean to get the count of doctors for each nickname or the count of nicknames for each doctor?

The subquery in the second query also doesn't make much sense:

```
SELECT   MAX(doctor_id) doctor_id,
         SUM(IF(pm='F', cost, NULL)) medicine,
         SUM(IF(pm='R', cost, NULL)) radiology,
         SUM(IF(pm='L', cost, NULL)) lab,
         SUM(IF(pm='P', cost, NULL)) act
FROM     c_table
GROUP BY Trans_No
```

Why are you grouping the trans_no?  Why aren't you using it as an index?

Perhaps you should write another question, explaining what you are trying to accomplish.